# How to check if program is running before deleting files in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to create a PowerShell script where first I'd like to check if a program is running and if not, then proceed to delete specific files. What I have so far is the following:

```
$Prog = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xyz.exe"
if ((Get-Process $Prog -EA SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
}
Remove-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\123.xml"
Remove-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\456.xml"
```

But this code deletes the files even if the program is running. So it ignores the first 2 (or 3) lines, before the `Remove-Item` commands.

Comment: Does this code produce an error, or not behave as intended?

Comment: I suggest you add that detail to the question, along with any attempts you've made to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is two-fold. First, `Get-Process` takes the Process Name in the `-Name` parameter not the process path. This means that `get-process $Prog -ea SilentlyContinue` will never return a process and will always be null.

You could use `Get-ChildItem` to get just the process name from the full path. Then if it needs to be from a specific path, you can filter using the `Path` property with `Where-Object` afterwards on the object returned.

Secondly, even when you do return a process with `Get-Process`. You have nothing to pause execution in the `if` statement, so it would just continue on. You could use a `while` loop and the `Start-Sleep` cmdlet, which would allow you to loop until the process was running.

```
$Prog = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xyz.exe"
$ProcessName = (Get-ChildItem $Prog).basename
while (!(Get-Process $ProcessName | Where-Object {$_.Path -eq $Prog})) {
    Start-Sleep 1
}
Remove-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\123.xml"
Remove-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\456.xml"
```